# Insert Adsense Ads on bottom as a sticky ads

Tags: javascript, html

I try to insert advertisement on bottom which is sticky it's working fine in desktop but didn't work on mobile device. Below is the code

```
    <script>
        var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
  var sticky_closed = false;
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if(!sticky_closed){
      var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
      if(docScroll <=90){
        $(".sticky-footer").slideUp();
      }else{
        $(".sticky-footer").slideDown();
      }
    }
  });
  $(".sticky-close").on('click',function(){
    footer = $(this).parent('.sticky-footer');
    footer.slideToggle();
    sticky_closed = true;
  });
</script>
```

Above code slide up ad when user scroll and i want to other user interaction like touchstart, mousemove, mousedown, etc so that it will work on all device.

HTML

```
     <div class="sticky-footer">
Ad
      <span class="sticky-close">X</span>
    </div>
```